# TextWatcher works but after text changed not

Tags: android, textview, textwatcher

This is my text watcher to control user's birth year enter. If user enters less than 1900 I want to replace it with 1900. App works properly. I can enter a value to `TextView`. But when start typing starts with "1" then immediately replacing to "1900" after I can't edit `TextView` again. Delete button on keypad does not delete entered value.

```
@Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            try {
                int birth = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());

                if (birth < 1900) {
                    s.replace(0, s.length(), "1900");
                }

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            }

        }
```

---

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:hint="Birth Year"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberSigned">
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright my Friend i've been thinking about it for a while here is the closest solution i could get. try this

```
@Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            try {
                int birth = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());

                if (birth < 1900 && s.length()>=4) {
                    s.replace(0, s.length(), "1900");
                }

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            }

        }
```

This is only a small modification on your if statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
replacing to "1900" after I can't edit TextView again. Delete button on keypad does not delete entered value.
```

This is expected behavior, It doesn't mean that delete button on keyboard does not delete the reentered value, Since after you replace the `1` to `1900` and then try to delete `0` (the last digit) will be deleted and immediately `afterTextChanged` will be called with input `190`, so your condition again satisfies to `<1900`  and the text is replace with `1900` again (this continues when you try to delete) .

I would suggest to add a check to see the `minimum length` of the input , I believe you expect the user to enter at least `4 digit`.

```
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    if(s.toString().length < 4) {
        return;
    }
      // do your other logic here

 }
```